# Fort space are both open and closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Let X be an infinite set and fixed point x0 belongs to X. Show that fort space, say A, on X in which every point, execpt x0, is both open and closed.

So what I have to prove is singleton sets which has elements of X are both open and closed?

Comment: You have to show that if $X$ is given the topology that makes it a Fort space with distinguished point $x_0$, then $\{x\}$ is both open and closed for every $x\in X\setminus\{x_0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

[Fort space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_space) open sets are defined as all sets that do not contain $x_0$, plus all sets that have a finite complement.

So if $x \neq x_0$, then $\{x\}$ does not contain $x_0$ so is by definition open.
On the other hand, $X\setminus \{x\}$ has a finite complement (namely $\{x\}$ again) so is open too, so $\{x\}$ is closed as its complement is open.

The set $\{x_0\}$ is not open because it does not obey either of the reasons to be open (in the definition): its complement is infinite (as $X$ is infinite) and it does contain $x_0$. It *is* closed, for the same reason as $\{x\}$ was before.

Just check the definitions, there's nothing more to it than that. "Points are open" is used here as a shorthand for "the singleton sets are open", which is more accurate.

So in $X\setminus \{x_0\}$ all singleton subsets are open, so $X\setminus \{x_0\}$ is discrete (and of the same size as $X$), and $x_0$ is a "compactifying point", just like the added point in the one-point compactification of a space (note that in a discrete set the compact closed subsets are just the finite ones, so that point would also get cofinite neighbourhoods). So Fort space is just the one-point compactification of a discrete space of size $|X|$, but we start with a set and choose the compactifying point to be $x_0 \in X$, as it were.